# Any one point me how to customize facebook share

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to share my own custom url, image, title and description using Facebook and twitter.

I am having lot of images and videos in my website. So i want to make my content viral on social websites. I am trying to keep share options for both facebook and twitter for everything individually. If some one share one image i want that image in the sharing thumbnail and url will be the page url with my own title, description. Based on the url i will point the user to that pic in my website.

I tried in the below way.

Facebook share:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=your_page_url','facebook share','resizable=yes,width=700,height=500,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')"><img alt="facebook" src="yourimage.jpg" /></a>
```

Twitter share:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/share','twitter share','resizable=yes,width=700,height=500,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')"><img alt="twitter" src="yourimage.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: check question i edited with more descritpion.

Comment: Why it's negative voted i didn't find solution any where in google. If you can't understand the question please comment or who ever negative voted please give me a reason. If i am wrong you can vote negative i don't have any problem.

Comment: First, I didn't down vote your question, 2nd do you use a server-side code like `PHP`? or any CMS?

Comment: i use plain php and Adam that comment if for people who negatively voted not for you.